# actions-on-google revoke token to allow re linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have enabled account linking in my dialogflow application which uses actions-on-google SDK.

I need to revoke account linking in some cases.

I can't find much help around this as to how I can remove linking so that the user has to go again through the account linking process.

I tried returning 401 - Unauthorize response however the application crashes and doesn't really clears the stored token.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you looking to unlink during development or a solution for a live action?

Comment: Live action. Through code

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify a couple of points? (1) Which form of account linking are you using (Google Sign-In or OAuth)? (2) If OAuth, what control over the OAuth server do you have? (3) You say you're "returning 401 - Unauthorize". Which service is returning this (OAuth, your fulfillment server, etc)?

Comment: I use oAuth. I do have some level of control on my server. I am returning 401 - Unauthorized from the actions-on-google fulfillment. I read that returning 401 would actually clear the token from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't have experience with doing unlinking through code because revoking access seems like something you don't want to do for the user in most cases, but this [topic](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) about revoking the accessToken for server side app on the Google Identity docs might be what you need.

It seems that you can revoke a token by sending a HTTP request to the oAuth services from Google and that should handle the revoking for you.

Comment: I tried both sending HTTP request to google to revoke but it always return with invalid token response. I tried sending 401 response through fulfilment but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Finally, actions-on-google support confirmed that they do not support programmatically unlinking. :(